# How to set OAuth Redirect URI to IP or DNS in Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to setup CI/CD for android application and publish APKs to Firebase and I am behind proxy

I was able to generate APK successfully by executing the command mentioned below on `Ubuntu 20 (server NOT client)` - 10.22.xx.xx

**Note:**  I connect to `Ubuntu Server` from my `Windows Desktop` using `PuTTY`

```
root@android:~/android-ur-app#./gradlew appDistributionLogin
```

and it provided me the following link to sign in.

Please open the following address in your browser:

```
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=5849e6.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:42319/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

I opened the link my **Windows Desktop Browser** and I was able to sign in with the firebase account but it failed with `"localhost refused to connect"` on `redirect_uri`

**Note:**  I understand that **NO process** is listening on **port# 42319** on my Windows Desktop

But, how can I change the `redirect_uri` in gradle from `'localhost'` to `'10.22.xx.xx'`

We also created a `DNS mapping` and tried hitting the URL with `'ourdomainname.com'` instead of `'localhost'` in `redirect_uri` which failed with

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

Kindly let me know how to set `redirect_uri` correctly in GRADLE to get the `firebase_access_token`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the proxy issue by adding the following to `'gradlew'` command

```
root@android:~/android-ur-app#./gradlew appDistributionLogin -Dhttps.proxyHost=10.xx.xx.xx -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 "-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=localhost" --stacktrace
```

Note:  We **should** add `"-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts=localhost"` and just adding `https.proxy` did **NOT** resolve the issue